# retriving a attribute value from xml column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
<storage xmlns="http://energy" created-on="2013-01-21T05:00:15Z">
<country>Italy</country>
<Points>
    <point>Callato;Cellino</point>
</Points>
    </storage>
```

above data is an column(xmlcolumn) in a table  i nned to retrieve the created on alone from the above. when i use  the query below i am getting null

```
 SELECT
 OutputXML.value('(storage/@created-on)[1]','date') 
  AS ProductType,*
FROM [DataOutput];
```

what is the error i am doing, Thanks Arun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the namespace for your query:

```
declare @t table (a xml)
insert into @t(a) values ('<storage xmlns="http://energy" created-on="2013-01-21T05:00:15Z">
<country>Italy</country>
<Points>
    <point>Callato;Cellino</point>
</Points>
    </storage>')

 SELECT
 a.value('declare namespace x = "http://energy";
          (x:storage/@created-on)[1]','date') 
  AS ProductType,*
FROM @t;
```

I've split it onto two lines for readability here. There's no need to do so however.

Result:

```
ProductType a
----------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2013-01-21  <storage xmlns="http://energy" created-on="2013-01-21T05:00:15Z"><country>Italy</country><Points><point>Callato;Cellino</point></Points></storage>
```